# CSV rows splitting and aligning in UNIX SCRIPT

Tags: shell, unix, csv

Is that possible to split and align rows of CSV like below?

```
ID Value
========
1  10
--------
2  20
--------
3  14
--------
```

Please consider the above as a csv, no need to care about 2nd column (Value).
I want to split the 1st Column (ID) and save the result/store it another file.

The output should like: 1,2,3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. In addition, please take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '!/^[-=]/ && NR!=1{str=str","$1}END{print substr(str,2)}'
```

tested [here](http://ideone.com/0nDIfO)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not well specified, but for your particular example you could do:

```
{ awk 'NR>2 && ! /^--/ { print $1 }' | tr \\n ,; echo; } < input > output
```

Or perhaps:

```
< input-file awk 'NR > 1 && NR%2 { print $1 }' | paste -d, -s > output
```